# Sorting s3 picture files according to size

Tags: amazon-web-services, sorting, amazon-s3, size

I want to map s3 bucket's picture files size.
Is it possible to get a bucket's file percentage which are bigger than 5mb?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't too clear, but it appears that you want to obtain information about the size of objects in an Amazon S3 bucket.

The [GET Bucket (List Objects) Version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) API call (and its equivalent in various SDKs such as [list-objects in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html) and [`list_objects_v2()` in Python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2)) will return a list of objects in a bucket, including the size of the objects. You could then use this information to calculate which objects are consuming the most storage space.

When listing objects, the only filter is the ability to specify a path (folder). It is not possible to list files based upon their size. Instead, all objects in the desired path will be returned.

If you have *many* objects (eg millions), it might be easier to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily CSV file listing all objects in a bucket.